# TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

im using devise for my login in rails but whenever i visit localhost:3000/users/sign_in 
im having this error

```
!! #<TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 91.91 given>
```

btw rails version is 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .jekyll-cache folder and start a fresh Jekyll serve

Answer (score -3):

Do `git clean -d -x -f` may can resolve the problem.

Comment: Warning: This will delete files such as `.env` ... use at your own risk

Comment: Every important file should be add to git already, so if you want to keep .env, just add it to git, if you want to keep security, export the ENV variable in bash profile.